# Adding a complex check constraint

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a table that has a compound primary key that includes a date.

```
Faculty

PersonId    StartDate    EndDate    Title ....

-------------------------------------------------
```

I will add a compound key consisting of the `PersonID` and `StartDate`. The business rule I am thinking about is allowing a person added as faculty, removed, and then added again later if needed. I am thinking a visiting professor. Or an adjunct who teaches an occasional course, but is not an active member of the faculty from one semester to the the next.

The end date will allow `nulls`, indicating a person is currently a faculty member.

I want to further constrain the data so a person can have only one row with an end date that is `null`.

Things I have considered:

- UDF in a check constraint
- Trigger (I hate triggers)
- Application layer constraint (most likely what I will do at this point)

Note:

- This is a hobby, work on this weekends kind of project
- The intended data store is Azure SQL Database

Comment: A unique constraint on PersonID EndDate ?

Comment: @Frisbee: NULL != NULL

Comment: This seems slightly off-topic to me. https://dba.stackexchange.com/ or SO, surely?

Comment: It's kind of difficult to tell where your actual question is in this post. Were you asking how to make your primary key support nulls properly? i.e., does Lightness' answer solve your problem?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Unique constraint is not a where clause

Comment: @Frisbee: I didn't say it was. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b887b92/2/0

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did try it out on sql-server and the question is tagged sql-server.  That fiddle is MySQL.

Comment: @Frisbee: Ah. What peculiar behaviour of MS SQL server. Apologies then.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I dithered on whether to put this on dba.stackexchange.com. Maybe I am off topic, but ultimately posted hear since I was thinking this was more of a data design question. I post to the DBA site with more nuts and bolts kinds of questions.

Comment: @lxrec Sorry if I am not clearer. Ultimately I was to allow many rows with a PersonId, StartDate, and EndDate. But only one row with where EndDate is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for SQL Server you can use a unique constraint

Just put a unique constraint on PersonID, EndDate
You can use null in a unique constraint and it enforces allow one null but not more

I tested this out and it does exactly what you are asking for
The only possible problem is this would not allow two identical non-null EndDate also - but I suspect that is what you want

[Unique Constraints and Check Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187550.aspx)

> Unlike PRIMARY KEY constraints, UNIQUE constraints allow for the value
>   NULL. However, as with any value participating in a UNIQUE constraint,
>   only one null value is allowed per column. A UNIQUE constraint can be
>   referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Fiddle is down

```
CREATE TABLE [t1](
    [col1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [col2] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [col3] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_t1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [col1] ASC,
    [col2] ASC
)
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_t1] ON [dbo].[t1]
(
    [col1] ASC,
    [col3] ASC
)
insert into t1 (1,1900-01-01,1900-01-01)
             , (1,1901-01-01,null)
             , (2,1900-01-01,1900-01-01)
             , (2,1902-01-01,1902-02-01)
```

Comment: I still wouldn't do it because it ruins portability.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, This may not be good for portability, but it does appear to do enforce the constraint I am aiming for.

Comment: @MikeHenderson Then consider checking it as the answer

Comment: @Frisbee Consider it done.

Comment: As long as you know there is no chance that you'll ever want to switch RDBMSes. If you have a lot of data, you may not wish then to translate it all to fit a standard-compliant RDBMS.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No chance ever?  If it has to be translated on a *slim* chance it is not much work.

Comment: @Frisbee: It could be a _huge_ amount of work, when the actual semantics of your 5TB database now need to be changed with a bunch of `UPDATE` statements and re-indexing, that now take hours or even days to run, just because you insisted upon using NULL instead of 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for frankly no good reason. And that's not even considering the cost of altering the application code that sits on top of it. What this suggestion does it to deliberately use a potentially costly non-portable solution for zero gain.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Easy dude. I really doubt a hobby project on a teacher schedule is 5MB let alone 5TB.   It is a single update statement and a single alter table statemetn.  I am not insisting on anything.  I am just answering the stated question.

Comment: I'm not your "dude". I'm just giving my opinion, and explaining it as challenged. You'll notice I did not cast any downvote.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  *Challenged?*  Notice I did not cast a down vote to your incorrect answer.   If you want to down vote me for a correct answer because I am supporting a potentially costly non-portable solution for zero gain then fine.   And I don't retaliate.

Comment: @Frisbee: No, I did not downvote _because_ I don't want to. Your answer _is_ correct. And I don't "retaliate" (wtf?!). I'm just discussing the portability situation. That's it, that's all. No need for the theatrics.